# implementing JS and support code into Bigcommerce to allow for user selectable dynamic drop down lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bigcommerce

I have written some JS and it's supporting CSS and HTML.  The end event will be for a bigcommerce user to select a model that is offered for sale and the options for that model selected will have sub options like materials it's made of , color, etc.

What will make this need additional coding from what BigCommerce already offers is this:

I want selections made earlier in the shopping experience to either enable or disable other later selectable options.  Example

If the user selects say "select material option below"  and then from that drop down selects "Walnut"  for the material option. all subsequent options for the rest of the shopping choices for this now walnut product will only show option choices for walnut products and will hide all Maple, Cocobolo, and Babinga options from later drop down lists

my cody can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/cogso0zj/3/

HTML:

```
`<div id="wrap">
 <select id="main-select">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="sub-select-1" class="sub-select" disabled="disabled">
<option value="foo">1 FOO</option>
</select>
<select id="sub-select-2" class="sub-select" disabled="disabled">
<option value="foo">2 FOO</option>
</select>
<select id="sub-select-3" class="sub-select" disabled="disabled">
<option value="foo">3 FOO</option>
</select>
</div>`
```

JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

   //do something when the main element is changed
   $('#main-select').change(
       function(e){

        //get what value was selected
        var val = $(this).val();


        //disable all sub selects, also hides them because of the css rule
        //note that using the disabled also prevents that element 
        //from submitting to the server, if you want all to submit
        //you use addClass('hidden') and removeClass('hidden') to 
        //hide them from the user
        //e.g. $('#sub-select-one').removeClass('hidden');

        //disabling all elements with sub-select class
        $('#wrap .sub-select').attr('disabled','disabled');

        //enable just the desired sub-select
        if(val == '1'){
            $('#sub-select-1').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else if(val=='2'){
            $('#sub-select-2').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else if(val=='3'){
           $('#sub-select-3').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
       }
      );
    });
```

Css:

```
select.sub-select[disabled="disabled"]{
    display: none;
}
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

Any clue what files I need to embed this in within BigCommerce to get it active

Comment: Is this supposed to be on the product page? I think I can help, but I need more info as to where its supposed to be and what changes its supposed to initiate on user interaction, in regards to BigCommerce functionality.